# How do i add an array of images?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add this code

```
Image[,] brickImage =  { { brickImageRed }, { brickImageBlue }, { brickImageGreen }, { brickImageBlack }, { brickImageYellow};
```

so that I can get my loop to select a different brick depending on a condition, but I get the error " a field initializer cannot reference the non static field, method or property..." what have I done wrong?

Comment: why are you using a 2D array like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you don't need to create multi dimensional array for this. I think single dimensional array would be ok for you as [dotnetstep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393736/3761928) has suggested.

**Problem:** Seems you are trying to use non-static member in any static method like `static main(args[])`

you should declare the `brickImage` array object to static.

```
static Image[] brickImage =  {  brickImageRed ,  brickImageBlue ,  brickImageGreen ,  brickImageBlack ,  brickImageYellow};
public static void main()
{
    //now u can use it here
}
```

**EDITE:** The object you have taken in the array should be also static member.

But, I would like to prefer to use `List<Bitmap>` instead of array.

```
static List<Bitmap> brickImage = new List<Bitmap>();
private static void myFunc()
{
    brickImage.Add(new Bitmap("Enter Image Path for red"));
    brickImage.Add(new Bitmap("Enter Image Path for green"));
    brickImage.Add(new Bitmap("Enter Image Path for blue"));
    ....

    foreach (Bitmap bmp in brickImage)
    {
        //Do whatever you want to do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple array.

```
Image[] brickImage =  {  brickImageRed ,  brickImageBlue ,  brickImageGreen ,  brickImageBlack ,  brickImageYellow};
```

Comment: im still getting the same error :/ it makes more sense now though as a simple array

Comment: For that I have to see more code. I feel that your array is static and you are trying to use class member.